# How can I turn on support package automatically

Tags: package

As I said in title, when you load a major mode like matlab-mode, I need company-mode as well. It's so easy to turn on the package, but is there any way to load automatically? through .emacs or .init ?

When I try to load 'matlab-shell', 'company-mode' is loaded without extra action for example.

I have no idea about LISP.

Comment: @lawlist I don't know how to thumbs-up. Thank you so much!

Comment: I wrote up a formal answer.  If that suffices, you can accept it.  As you gain reputation in this forum, you will have more voting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions for `company-mode` at https://company-mode.github.io/ say: "*To use company-mode in all buffers, add the following line to your init file*":

```lisp
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
```

To use `company-mode` in only certain major-modes, use something like this (where the first argument to `add-hook` is the name of the applicable major-mode hook):

```lisp
(add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook 'company-mode)
```